# SVD solvez with OpenCV java wrapper

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm porting some C++ code using the OpenCV_2.4.11 java wrapper (on Android). I have the following C++ lines:

```
Matx44d A(...);
Matx41d u;

SVD svd;
svd.solveZ(A, u);
```

In java, I have:

```
    Mat A = new Mat(4, 4, CvType.CV_32F);
    A.put(0 ,0, ...
    Mat u = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
```

How can I translate the last two lines using the OpenCV java wrapper?

Comment: I don't know about `solveZ`, but the first part is in the doc.
http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html #SVDecomp(org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Mat) [SO does not display URL correctly, just remove the space before `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.opencv.core.Core.solve(AA, BB, XX, org.opencv.core.Core.DECOMP_SVD);
```